# AngularJS - Issues with references when using services and ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Im finding myself fighting with 'pointers' in javascript. It's like I'm in C++ again. I would like to know your approach to the following issue Im having.

My case: I have a *`ng-repeat`* that goes over a *`collection`*. When ***clicking one*** of the collection elements, ***I do a copy of the element***, ***do changes*** over it ***and POST/PUT data to server***.

If the ***server replies 200*** then I will ***apply those changes to the collection***. The collection contains objects, so it means that Im working with references NOT values.

The module definition with a service:

```
angular.module('dataModule', [])

    .service('DataService', function () {
        this.collection = [{id:0, who: 'I'},
                           {id:1, who: 'YOU'}, 
                           {id:2, who: 'HE'},
                           {id:3, who: 'SHE'},
                           {id:4, who: 'IT'}];
})
```

And here the controller:

```
.controller('listCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout, DataService) {
    // Data used in view
    $scope.collection = DataService.collection;

    // Action trigger from the view
    $scope.change = function(data, index){
        // Get a copy 
        var copy = angular.copy(data);

        // Apply changes over the copy
        copy.id = data.id*100*index;

        // Simulate POSTing/Updating data to server
        console.log('Sending data to server...');
        $timeout(function(){
            // Response is 200
            var response = 200;

            // Assigning copy -> data
            data = copy;

            // The prev. assignment is not updating the collection
            // Of course I could do $scope.collection[index] = copy; 
            //  because this case is simple enough.
            // Im finding myself having the service with methods find, edit, ...
            // What's a better approach?

        }, 2000)
    }
});
```

As I said in the comments, Im finding myself implementing functions like find, edit or get in the service. Is that the approach to go???

Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kitimenpolku/M66LV/5/ in case I was not able to explain it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my perspective, there are two ways you can go with updating the view after you write to the server:

1. You ask the server for the entire collection again, and then set it
   locally.  This requires the use of promises and replacing the
   current collection with a new one.  This replacement will
   automatically trigger an update in the `ng-repeat` directive you are
   using in your template.
2. You perform the same transformation locally, as you mentioned yourself.  This entails finding the correct index of the array and swapping out the old object for the edited one.  This is how I like to setup my own applications and it's really not so hard to do.  Here's how:

I can see that you really are thinking of this javascript replacement as if it were in c++.  Here, you are correct in that `data = copy;` in your server callback is merely updating a reference, not any data itself.

Instead, you can alter the collection itself directly: `$scope.collection[index] = copy`

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wilsonjonash/GZ2eR/

Answer (score 1):

`data` is a reference to the original item but using `data = copy` is just invalidating data so the original never gets updated.

So to update the original item you need to perform.

```
 data.id = copy.id;
 data.who = copy.who;
```

or

```
$scopy.collection[index] = copy
```

fiddle with updated code

http://jsfiddle.net/M66LV/7/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I have mentioned in the example under comments, I can totally do $scopy.collection[index] = copy.That's the easy way for simple data like this... but I don't think I should do it when having a collection with 2000 elements or more... if index gets corrupted or does not refresh, I could update something that is totally different... so Im finding myself using lodash.find or underscore.find to get the object by id. Anything better than this? Or is this the 'right' approach?

Comment: @kitimenpolku, to me, that approach is just fine.  I would use `underscore.find` or even just the built-in `Array.filter` to find the one object by its ID, then pass that object to `Array.indexOf` to get the index; then I would use that index to update the array directly, as illustrated in both answers.  This can be an effective approach. I don't think there is any one "right" approach.

Comment: @kitimenpolku yes you should add methods to your service to manage it's own data but this is only because you might be reusing your service in other controllers and you would want to centralize your logic to perform this data management.